# Login web server api JSON button click not working

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I am Trying to make a login app which will connect with the web server api. When I build the files in android studio, everything goes fine. But after running app in the emulator/real android device, when I click the login button, The app has stopped.

MainActivity is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextInputLayout username, password;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/solaimanlipi.ttf");
    myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
    initializtion();

}

private void initializtion() {
    final TextInputLayout username = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.username);
    final TextInputLayout password = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
    username.setHint("Username");
    password.setHint("Password");
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    if(id == R.id.button){
        if (!CommonTask.isOnline(this)) {
            CommonTask.goSettingPage(this);
            return;
        }
        validation_check();
    }
}

private void validation_check() {
    if(username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        username.setError("Please enter user name");
        return;
    }
    if(password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        password.setError("Please enter your password");
        return;
    }
    doLogin();
}

private void doLogin() {

    try{

        String url=String.format(CommonURL.getInstance().login,username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim(),
                password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Login , Please wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, "",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject obj) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if(obj != null){
                            LoginResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(obj.toString(), LoginResponse.class);
                            if(response.result.equals("valid")){

                                CommonTask.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), CommonContents.USERNAME,username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
                                CommonTask.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), CommonContents.PASSWORD,password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
                                CommonTask.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), CommonContents.isLoggedIn,"1");
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong UserID or Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MainApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, "Login");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        CommonTask.showLog(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

But when I click the button, Android Studio gives me this logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.mateors.mastererp.activity.MainActivity.validation_check(MainActivity.java:68)
                  at com.mateors.mastererp.activity.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your JSON respnse...

Comment: Is it crashing when username or password is empty? And which one is line 68?

Answer (score 2):

In your `initialization` function you don't have to declare the `username` and `password` field again. The global variables should be used here. You're declaring two local variables in your code which is wrong and can not be found outside of this scope.

Here's the modified `initialization` function.

```
private void initializtion() {
    username = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
    username.setHint("Username");
    password.setHint("Password");
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Now inside the `validation_check` function you need to get the text from those `EditText` like this.

```
private void validation_check() {
    if(username.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        username.setError("Please enter user name");
        return;
    }

    if(password.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        password.setError("Please enter your password");
        return;
    }

    doLogin();
}
```

This will do.